# How to reference local variables from within a mongoose `$where()` query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I reference a local variable from within a `$where` query in Mongoose?
For example:

```
var testName = 'Some Dude';
Cab.$where('this.name === testName').exec((_err, cabs) => {
    // Do something...
});
```

If `testName` will be decided on runtime, how should it be referenced in the query?
My actual query is a bit complicated so I need to execute a Javascript expression.
I've tried using `this.testName` which didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use ES6 template literals, e.g.:

```
var testName = 'Some Dude';
Cab.$where(`this.name === ${testName}`).exec((_err, cabs) => {
    // Do something...
});
```